# Putting each line of tailwindcss code on new line in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio, tailwind-css

Hi I often write long CSS class declarations when using tailwindcss in visual studio. Wondered if there was a setting / plugin so that the CSS wraps to resemble CSS in a CSS file something like

```
<div class="
w-full
h-full
flex
items-center
justify-center
"
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you find a way to do this?